# Deleting a marker from folium map

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, folium

I am making an application in which I have a stream of locations which I need to mark on a map. I show only a particular number of markers on the map, so I need to replace a few of the old markers with new markers.

I am using `folium.simple_marker()` to mark the locations.

Is there a function to delete a specific marker?

```
import folium
map_1 = folium.Map(location=[latitude,longtitude], zoom_start=9,)
for location in locations:
   map_1.simple_marker([location.lat,location.longt], popup='')
map_1.create_map(path='map.html')
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not a built-in function, but you can use

```
del map_1.template_vars.get('custom_markers')[0]
```

This removes the oldest marker in the map object. That is a standard python call. I could not find anything in `folium` that does what you need.

It seems as though all of the `map`'s objects are in its `template_vars` dictionary, by the way.

Comment: For any others finding this, I _think_ this might be outdated now. My map has no `.tempate_vars` entry.

Comment: Maybe this solution is deprecated.
My map have no .template_vars.

```python
del paris.template_vars.get('custom_markers')[0]
paris
```

Error : 
```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-8a41c97e81f7> in <module>
----> 1 del paris.template_vars.get('custom_markers')[0]
      2 paris

AttributeError: 'Map' object has no attribute 'template_vars'
```